# "ages" for "who are of the ages"

Tags: ellipsis

Some people say "ages" below is short for the relative clause "who are of the ages." If so, I'm wondering whether other relative clauses can be shortened into nouns this way, i.e., by removing "who Be of the."

> Make-A-Wish Mississippi, which grants wishes to children and teens **ages** 2–18 who are often battling devastating illnesses, made his wish come true.

Comment: Vehicles weight 3 tons or more are banned from this bridge.

Comment: Is that a grammatical sentence? I'm surprised!

Comment: You see abbreviated sentences on warning notices. 'In case of fire, leave building!'

Comment: I find that usage odd - I would have said **aged 2-18**.

Comment: The sentence above is common in AmE.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Is "Vehicles weight 3 tons or more are banned from this bridge" natural in AmE?

Comment: @Apollyon The original sentence structure is common in AmE. "zzz...grants wishes to children and teens **ages 2-18**..."

Comment: @FeliniusRex Yes, but the structure is hardly reproducible with other nouns than "ages."